# Ember-ajax how to add global error handler like in jQuery.ajaxSetup()

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js

I'm using ember-ajax which I have to inject in my components as a service to use it. Is there a way to add a global error handler like in `$.ajaxSetup()`?

I'd like to redirect the users to the login page if their authentication is expired, thus an error would pop-up through the ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember-ajax uses as response RSVP objects, thus I just had to catch errors given by RSVP objects.

I wrote an initializer service to do this job. This is my initializer:

```
export function initialize( application ) {
    Ember.RSVP.on('error', function(error) {
        if (error['status'] === 404 || error['status'] !== 500) {
             console.log("could not load");
        }
        if (error['message'] === "The adapter operation was aborted") {
             window.location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If server returns error for any of API due to exceptions, then your code will try to reload, and again you get an error and you will reload thus it will create endless loop. Am i right ?. May be you might need to check for 401 error code before doing `location.reload()`

Comment: Right, it's good practice to check the status code, or an specific error. In my case I check for the message "The adapter operation was aborted". I will update my answer for completion sake. Thanks, @kumkanillam